# What's the meaning of "Turning back to the class at large" in this context?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> Neville nodded nervously, but Moody made no further inquiries. Turning back to the class **at large**, he reached into the jar for the next spider and placed it upon the desktop, where it remained motionless, apparently too scared to move.

This is a scene from *Harry Potter And the Goblet of Fire* in which Moody showed three unforgivable curses to the students. After Moody had used a curse to torture the first spider, Neville Longbottom gave the second correct curse name: `the Cruciatus Curse` and Moody is poised to use it on the second spider.

"At large" has the meaning: `at liberty; escaped or not yet captured.`

"Turning back to the class at large" seems to be saying that Moody tortures spiders cruelly without fear of punishment?

Comment: **at large** is an idiomatic expression. It has several possible meanings depending on the context.  The **at liberty, escaped** sense is used when referring to criminals or a dangerous person/animal.  In the example however, **at large** has a different meaning here. It means **as a a whole**.  You could reword it as **the whole class**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At large has different meanings: ([Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/large_1#large_idmg_1))

> 1. ​(of a dangerous person or animal) **not captured; free**
>    *Her killer is still at large.*

> 2. (used after a noun) **as a whole; in general**
>    *the opinion of the public at large*

This means that the **teacher turned his/her attention back (from a particular student) to the whole class**.